# ExtJS 4.2.1 - getters/setters using Associations not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, associations, setter, getter

I'm having trouble trying to invoke getters/setters on a Model object that has an association with one other model.  Here are the classes:

Category.js

```
Ext.define('Chapter05.model.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id',   type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
})
```

Product.js

```
Ext.define('Chapter05.model.Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Chapter05.model.Category'
    ],

    fields: [
        { name: 'id',          type: 'int' },
        { name: 'category_id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name',        type: 'string' }
    ],
    // we can use the belongsTo shortcut on the model to create a belongsTo association
    associations: [
        { type: 'belongsTo', model: 'Chapter05.model.Category' }
    ]
})
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define('Chapter05.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires:[
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
        'Chapter05.model.Product',
        'Chapter05.model.Category',
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',
    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Category',

            handler: function(evt) {
                var product = new Chapter05.model.Product({
                    id: 100,
                    category_id: 20,
                    name: 'Sneakers'
                });

                product.getCategory(function(category, operation) {
                    // do something with the category object
                    alert(category.get('id')); // alerts 20
                }, this);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The error occurs at the line where product.getCategory(...) is.  I get the following message in Safari Web Inspector:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'product.getCategory')
```

Am I forgetting to do something?

P.S.
The project(Chapter05) was generated using Sencha Cmd.  Hence, the fully qualified names.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with a `hasOne` relation. It was solved by specifying the getters/setters and the associationKey yourself.

Something like:

```
belongsTo: {
    model: 'Chapter05.model.Category',
    getterName: 'getCategory',
    setterName: 'setCategory',
    associationKey: 'category_id'
}
```

Comment: I added all the stuff from your post, but now I got this error instead: Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.  Did a quick search on Google and tried adding idProperty field to both of the Models as well.  Still got the same error.  Any ideas?